# Option to use AirPort Express with 1 TB harddrive for Dropbox equivalent

Tags: network, wifi, hard-drive, airport, storage

I have an AirPort Express with a 1 TB harddrive, obviously this airport is connected to the internet and in the next month our house will be conected to the optic fibre network giving us 200 megabits/seconds connection speed. Now to me this looks like a great opertunity to store some fairly large files on a shared disk.

One problem is that the AirPort Express also functions as the backup device, so ideally we would only split of 100 GB so as to allow the other 900 GB to continue functioning as a Time Machine. Idealy this would be approachable from both inside and outside the network (with passwords!) so that I can connect to it from a university as well as at home.

Additionally the network has the following operating systems connected to it that would ideally also be able to connect to the harddrive: OS X Yosemite, Ubuntu 14.04, Windows 7 and probably in the near future a Linux Mint installation.

Answer (score 1):

You can surely do this but please not that doing so will void your Apple warranty with the Airport Extreme.

What you need to do is:

1. Pull the HDD out of the Time Capsule (take it apart)
2. Install the HDD in an enclosure or caddy
3. Connect the enclosure to your Mac
4. Use Disk Utility to create a 100GB partition
5. Reinstall the HDD in your Airport Extreme and you are good to go!

When you partition the drive anything stored on it should not be affected since it is only resizing the current partition.

Comment: That would get me a partitioned harddrive, is there any way to then connect to the airport from outside the network?

Comment: Yup you can. You can use a DDNS like no-ip.org. This is how you can configure it. 
1) Setup a DDNS account. 
2) Airport Utility > Select base station > Manual Setup > Airport > Base station tab > Edit... 
3) Use global dynamic hostname is checked 
4) Enter your hostname and username and password from no-ip.org 
5) AirPort Utility > Select the base station > Manual Setup > Disks > File Sharing tab > Share disks over the Internet with Bonjour (checked)

To access disk:
OS X: Finder > Go > Connect to Server > Server Address: <your DynDNS Global Host Name>

Comment: Alright I now seem to be able to connect to it from within the network but when I try to connect to it over the no.ip.org it seems unwilling to do anything. How do I connect to it from outside the network?

Answer (score 0):

I see some issues with your plan...

Dropbox is a 'share once, download many' solution.

Providing your own 'file-server' is a 'share every single time' plan.

If your new connection is going to be 200Mb/s **both ways** & you also have a no-limit plan, then that may be all fair & good, but most domestic connections are 10:1 - that is, for every 10Mb download speed, you get 1Mb upload speed, so if you have a few people needing your shares, you'll quickly kill your connectivity.